# How to indicate type of each attribute in SAS studio

Tags: excel, sas, statistics, attributes, dataset

How can I indicate type of each attribute of dataset in SAS studio?
How to find nominal, ordinal, interval or ration of dataset by using SAS?

Comment: As posted this question is a bit unclear, if you add some details and an example it may help. Please see the rules on how to ask a question [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have rules that you want to implement? SAS does have a 'Characterize Data' task that attempts to do this, but only for categorical or continuous variables. It's impossible to tell the difference between an ordinal and nominal variable automatically.

The rules usually are based on the Number of unique values, ie if a variable only has 5 unique values it's likely categorical. That cutoff can be controlled in the task.

Otherwise, in general, this is a best guess. SAS EM does have some more rules/routines but I'm going to guess you don't have access to that.